# My children paths in vue refuse to render their view when resolved, they are rendering the parent view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've tried redoing the whole process, refactoring the code a bit (I'm still rather new to vue so some of my code is a bit sloppy) but nothing seems to render the component for the child path. It always resolves to the parent path.

The code in my products.js (all paths under products)

```
import Products from '../views/Products.vue'
import Product from '../views/Product.vue'

export default {
  path: '/products',
  name: 'Products',
  component: Products,
  children: [
    {
      path: ':id',
      name: 'OneProduct',
      component: Product
    }
  ]
}
```

The code in my product.view (the view for the path: /products/:id)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ExpandedProduct
      :prodNmae="$route.query.productName"
      :price="$route.query.prodPrice"
      :description="$route.query.description"
      />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ExpandedProduct from '../components/ExpandedProduct'

export default {
  name: 'Product',
  components: {
    ExpandedProduct
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

the ExpandedProduct component is the component which is supposed to be rendered when the route resolves to '/products/:id'
ExpandedProduct.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="carousel-holder">
      <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item
          v-for="(item,i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :src="item.src"
          reverse-transition="fade-transition"
          transition="fade-transition"
        ></v-carousel-item>
      </v-carousel>
    </div>
    <div class="description-holder">
      <h2>{{ $route.query }}</h2>
      <h4>{{ $route.query.prodPrice }}</h4>
      <h3>{{ $route.query.description }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ExpandedProduct',
  props: {
    prodName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'N/A'
    },
    price: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'N/A'
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'N/A'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/squirrel.jpg' },
        { src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg' },
        { src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg' },
        { src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

If someone could explain to me what I'm missing

Comment: Place `:id` in parent path, as shown in [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

Comment: That would be a sure fix, however, I want have a /products path that renders all the products from my backend, doing so would fix my parent path to specific products only

Comment: Then you don't want children. You want two top routes: `[{ path: 'products', component: ProductsList }, {path: 'products/:id', component: SingleProduct }]`. Right?

Comment: How are you navigating to each child?

Comment: @simbamufasa you're missing a second `router-view` - if you want nested routes.

Comment: Yeah the solution is definitely two top routes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `/product` route and a separate `/product/:id` route is not the same as adding `children` with `:id` to a parent `/product` route.

The former creates a page without the `:id` parameter and a page that handles the `:id` parameter. The latter creates ONE page and a child `router-view` gets the `:id` parameter.

I think it's better explained with snippets:

#### 1. This is the `/product` + `/product/:id`

```js
const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>Foo</div>
  `
}

const FooId = {
  template: `
    <div>Foo+{{ $route.params.id }}</div>
  `
}

const Bar = {
  template: `
    <div>Bar</div>
  `
}

const Baz = {
  template: `
    <div>Baz</div>
  `
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/foo',
    component: Foo
  },
  {
    path: '/foo/:id',
    component: FooId
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    component: Bar
  },
  {
    path: '/baz',
    component: Baz
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app",
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>APP</h3>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/foo/1">Go to Foo-1</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/foo/2">Go to Foo-2</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/baz">Go to Baz</router-link><br />
  </p>
  <h3>ROUTES:</h3>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

#### 2. This is the `/product` parent + `:id` children

```js
const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>
      Foo
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  `
}

const FooId = {
  template: `
    <div>Foo+{{ $route.params.id }}</div>
  `
}

const Bar = {
  template: `
    <div>Bar</div>
  `
}

const Baz = {
  template: `
    <div>Baz</div>
  `
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/foo',
    component: Foo,
    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      component: FooId
    }]
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    component: Bar
  },
  {
    path: '/baz',
    component: Baz
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app",
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>APP</h3>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/foo/1">Go to Foo-1</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/foo/2">Go to Foo-2</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link><br />
    <router-link to="/baz">Go to Baz</router-link><br />
  </p>
  <h3>ROUTES:</h3>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

#### 3. Difference

The other name for `children` routes is **nested** routes. That means that a route is treated as root, and there's another `router-view` inside it (Ok, this is only for concept-explanation). ([Nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes))

---

So, the **question is**: do you want separate pages for **products** and each **product** (v1 - two separate routes), or you want a parent page for all your **products** and control the subsection of THAT page for each **product** (v2 - nested routes).

#### EDIT

Added a bit of CSS, so it's more understandable that what's inside what.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've decided to go with the /product and /product/:id solution. Although it's not as modular as I'd want it to be, it seems easier to understand because both paths get treated as root instead of nesting it all, which again goes against modularity

Comment: @simbamufasa I’m glad that I could help! I think both directions can be good - it’s only depending on the task at hand. :)